# How to share content of a span on twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to share content of span with id 'randomSpan' via twitter. Is this possible?
So far I have this html and function that generates quotes.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>RANDOM QUOTES</h1>
  <span id="randomSpan">Click the button</span>
  <button id='getRandom' onclick="randomQuote();">CLICK FOR A QUOTE</button>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" {count} data-url="goo.gl/udj2qQ" data-text="blabla">Tweet</a>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
  </script>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/mPreGM)

Answer (score 0):

UPD

Managed to get something like this working but it is sharing whole array instead of elements

[codePen](http://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/mPreGM)

HTML

```
 <a id="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("twitter").innerHTML =
    "<a href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + aQuote + "&hashtags=randomQuote' target='_blank'>\
        <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></a>"
```

Comment: It's sharing the whole array because `aQuote` refers to the whole array. Use `aQuote[rdmQuote]` instead when generating the URL, and consider renaming your variables so you don't get mislead again, e.g. something like: `aQuote -> quoteList`, `rdmQuote -> rdmQuoteIdx`, `rdmQuote = quoteList[rdmQuoteIdx]` .

Comment: Thanks for the advice about renaming variables. Now everything works =)